# The argument type 'LatLng' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng?'

Tags: flutter, dart

when am using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) in MapOptions-> Center when entering the lat and lng am getting an error The argument type 'LatLng' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng?'.

```
class MapsView extends HookConsumerWidget {
  MapsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
   final MapController _mapController=MapController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
       center: LatLng(51.509364, -0.128928),
        zoom: 9.2,
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
          urlTemplate: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
          userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
        ),
      ],
      nonRotatedChildren: [
        AttributionWidget.defaultWidget(
          source: 'OpenStreetMap contributors',
          onSourceTapped: null,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  }
```

[image: screen shot of the error]

Comment: Could you please update question with your package imports for this widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
 class MapsView extends HookConsumerWidget {
  MapsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 final MapController _mapController=MapController();

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
return FlutterMap(
  options: MapOptions(
   center: LatLng(51.509364, -0.128928),
    zoom: 9.2,
  ),
  layers: [
    TileLayerOptions(
      urlTemplate: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
    ),
  ],
  nonRotatedChildren: [
    AttributionWidget.defaultWidget(
      source: 'OpenStreetMap contributors',
      onSourceTapped: null,
    ),
  ],
);
}

 }
```

**import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart**

that is not exported in the package so you have to import this manually to be able to assign values in it
[image: Their website recomendation]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need are not using latLng2

> ```
> dependencies:
>   latlong2: ^0.8.0
> ```

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latLng;

FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
       center: latLng.LatLng(51.509364, -0.128928),
        zoom: 9.2,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already using   `latlong: ^0.6.1` or higher
then you need to change your import
from:

```
import "package:latlong/latlong.dart" as latLng;
```

to:

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latLng;
```

and it will be fine.