# The argument type 'LatLng' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng*'

Tags: flutter

I get this error :
The argument type 'LatLng' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'LatLng*'

this is not like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341777/the-argument-type-latlng-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-latlng) that is asked before.

I import all needed package that recommended on doc of flutter_map.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/plugin_api.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
```

I assign LatLng to center.

```
options: MapOptions(
          center: LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
          zoom: 4.0,
          maxZoom: 19.0,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved

in import list I removed 2 from latlong2 to become

```
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
```

and it worked. even that in the [documentation](https://docs.fleaflet.dev/getting-started/additional-setup)  we have 2 in backage name

Answer (score 0):

Try with prefix

```dart
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latlg2;
...
 center: latlg2.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
```

Comment: THanks but it didn't work. still give the same error.

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: did it, still show the error

Comment: Do you just have `latlong` package?  Remove that.

Comment: it worked, I delete number 2 in import latlong2, to becoume import latlong. in the documentation there is 2 and in bachage name in yaml file there is 2 too

Comment: Well I was referring to have `latlong2` and removing `latlong`

Answer (score 0):

flutter_map maintainer here. Indeed, @Nordeen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73572986/11846040) is correct.

There are many 'latlong'/'latlng' packages available, and we chose 'latlong2', as it was the latest at the time of migration to null-safety.

Please install this package in your pubspec.yaml, then depend on it with:

```dart
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
```

If you need more help, please read the docs: https://docs.fleaflet.dev/getting-started/additional-setup. We're also always happy to help on the Discord server :)